# How to create form with multiple records?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a model Product with a name of product and a model ProductCosts with a cost value which is connected to the Product model.

I have currently a form for input of new product and another form for input of costs, where I can select product and add costs to this new product.

And is there some way how to create a form which will show product names which are missing costs in one column and in the second column blank fields for input of product costs and there will be x rows based on number of products which are currently without costs?

(There is also another filed with number of produced products in ProductCosts, but I ignored it to simplify my question.)

My models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Product", max_length=150)
    ...

class ProductCosts(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    costs = models.DecimalField("Costs", max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    produced = models.IntegerField("Produced", null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

form.py

```
class ProductCostsForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.ProductCosts
        fields = ["product", "costs", "produced"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div("product", css_class="col-12"),
                css_class="row",
            ),
            Div(
                Div("costs", css_class="col-6"),
                Div("produced", css_class="col-6"),
                css_class="row",
            ),
            Div(
                Div(HTML('<hr>'), css_class="col-12"),
                css_class="row",
            ),
        )
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class="col-4 btn btn-dark text-center justify-content-center"))
```